# Is TMP really faster if the recusion depth is very deep?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I made a simple `sqrt` struct using TMP. It goes like :

```
template <int N, int i>
struct sqrt {
    static const int val = (i*i <= N && (i + 1)*(i + 1) > N) ? i : sqrt<N, i - 1 >::val;
};
```

but is causes error since it does not have the exit condition, so I added this :

```
template <int N>
struct sqrtM<N, 0> {
    static const int val = 0;
};
```

So as I understand it, in case we use TMP, the compiler goes into recursion loop until they meet the exit condition (in terms of `sqrt`, usally when i = 0 or i = 1)

But if we make a recursive `sqrt` function, compiler doesn't have to dive until it meets `i = 0`, because at some point, recursive function ends at exact location where condition `(i*i <= N && (i + 1)*(i + 1) > N)` is met.

So let's assume we put very large value into our `sqrt`, then our TMP should do extra computation of `sqrt<N, sqrt<N-1>::val>` compared to the recursive version of `sqrt` function, and it seems waste to me.

Am I getting it wrong? Or TMP is really worth it even in this kind of cases?

Comment: The condition `(i*i <= N && (i + 1)*(i + 1) > N)` does not terminate the compiler's recursion, because this expression is part of a larger one that contains `sqrt<N, i - 1 >`; so, the compiler still has to expand every template down to `sqrt<N, 0 >`. Use `if constexpr` to terminate the recursion early.

Comment: `Am I getting it wrong? Or TMP is really worth it even in this kind of cases?` as usual, it depends. You (or the programmer/designer in general) are the one to measure it and take potential tradeoffs of compilation time vs runtime.

Comment: Probably the recursion for the square root could be optimized to converge in much less steps. Use Newton's formula.

Comment: The question in the title is unclear. Is TMP faster than what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that in TMP you can't go very deep by default. The depth is limited but the limit can be changed (see [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-and-cpp-linux/13.1.1?topic=descriptions-ftemplate-depth-qtemplatedepth-only)). The other thing is that you write your TMP code with recursion but it can be compiled into a non-recursive code so it doesn't have the extra cost of saving the state and doing a function call as it goes deeper. So it is a tradeoff between compile time, executable size and runtime performance. If your N is not known at compile time, then you can't use TMP.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between evaluation and instantiation.

in

```
template <int N, int i>
struct sqrt {
    static const int val = (i*i <= N && (i + 1)*(i + 1) > N) ? i : sqrt<N, i - 1 >::val;
};
```

it should instantiate `sqrt<N, i - 1 >` to retrieve associated `val`, even if that value won't be taken at the end.

You can write code differently to delay instantiation of `sqrt<N, i - 1 >`

```
template <int N> struct val_identity { static const int val = N; };

template <int N, int i>
struct sqrt {
    static const int val =
        std::conditional_t<i * i <= N && N < (i + 1) * (i + 1),
                           val_identity<i>,
                           sqrt<N, i - 1 >
                          >::val;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b64d6f1jK)